# Actualizar datos a 0 para luego copiar una tabla a otra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia, lo que quiero hacer es actualizar una tabla (Inventario) de una tabla temporal (TemporalInventarioMarzo) pero antes de eso poner la columna de Cantidad en 0 de todos los articulos.

```
update Inventario set Cantidad ='0'
       From Inventario
               Inner Join TemporalInvetarioMarzo as temp on 
                  temp.CodigoArticulo = Inventario.CodigoArticulo and
temp.CodigoSucursal = 'V1'
```

Pero al momento de correr el query me pone todos los articulos a una misma cantidad y no los pone primero en ceros

Despues intente con este

```
update Inventario set Cantidad=temp.cantidad 
      from inventario inner join TemporalInventarioMarzo as temp 
        on temp.CodigoArticulo=inventario.CodigoArticulo and temp.CodigoSucursal='v1'
```

Pero siguio el mismo problema

Comment: Para poner todos los registros a 0 sólo necesitas hacer un `UPDATE Inventario set Cantidad=0`

Comment: Podes poner un ejemplo con datos de lo que queres hacer. No se entiende porque decis que no funciona, o que es lo que no funciona? pone algunos datos de origen, como te esta quedando, y como queres que quede

Comment: Crees que ayude esto 

me actualiza todos los campos de cantidad a la misma cantidad 
https://ibb.co/fdbJg6x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema con el primer UPDATE

```
UPDATE i 
SET Cantidad = 0
FROM Inventario i
INNER JOIN TemporalInvetarioMarzo AS temp ON temp.CodigoArticulo = i.CodigoArticulo 
                                         AND temp.CodigoSucursal = 'V1';
```

Es que sólo va a actualizar los artículos que cumplan con el JOIN.

Para actualizar todos los artículos y asignar la cantidad del inventario de marzo o un cero a los que no existan, podemos usar un LEFT JOIN con ISNULL.

```
UPDATE i 
SET Cantidad = ISNULL( temp.cantidad, 0)
FROM Inventario i
LEFT JOIN TemporalInvetarioMarzo AS temp ON temp.CodigoArticulo = i.CodigoArticulo 
                                        AND temp.CodigoSucursal = i.CodigoSucursal
WHERE i.CodigoSucursal = 'V1';
```

Así cuando no haya una fila correspondiente en el inventario de marzo, regresará NULL y ese NULL lo convertiremos en cero.

Alguna gente que está acostumbrada a otros RDBMS pueden usar una sintaxis un poco distinta.

```
UPDATE i 
SET Cantidad = ISNULL( (SELECT temp.cantidad
                        FROM TemporalInvetarioMarzo AS temp 
                        WHERE temp.CodigoArticulo = i.CodigoArticulo  
                        AND temp.CodigoSucursal = i.CodigoSucursal), 0)
FROM Inventario i
WHERE i.CodigoSucursal = 'V1';
```

Comment: Me ayudo la verdad pero al momento de comparar los resultados me manda todos los artículos a la misma cantidad @gbianchi no se si te ayude esto https://ibb.co/fdbJg6x

Comment: Es porque te falta una condición en el JOIN. Voy a editar la respuesta para aplicar lo correcto.

Comment: Me mando los resultados a 0 excepto de la sucursal V1

Comment: Y no era lo que querías?

Comment: Si y no... perdon si me explico mal, los articulos que no existieran la cantidad fr estos la pondria como null y luego se transforma en 0, pero solo actualizar los registros de v1 sin afectar a las demas
https://ibb.co/F4dkqFg

Comment: Pues eso lo limitas en el WHERE.

Comment: Ya funciono 
update d set d.Cantidad = isnull(t.Cantidad, 0) from Inventario d inner join TemporalInventarioMarzo t on d.CodigoArticulo = t.CodigoArticulo where d.Codigosucursal ='V1' 

O en su caso a la sucursal correspondiente a  actualizar

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya funciono gracias a @Luis

```
update d set d.Cantidad = isnull(t.Cantidad, 0) 
   from Inventario d inner join TemporalInventarioMarzo t on 
     d.CodigoArticulo = t.CodigoArticulo 
        where d.Codigosucursal ='V1' and t.Codigosucursal ='V1'
```

O en su caso a la sucursal correspondiente a  actualizar